# Prove the zero in the complex number system is unique.

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove the zero in the complex number system is unique.

 I have an idea but i don't know how start this proof.

**The idea:** 
I think start out with the assumption that there exist two different unities, say, $a$ and $b$, and then proceeds to show that this assumption leads to some contradiction.

But i'm a little stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Unique in what way? For example, unique as a complex number $z$ such that $a + z = z + a = a$ for any $a$? Or such that $za = az = z$ for any $a$? I'm also confused by your term "unities"...

Comment: This clearly depends on your choice of definition. If complex number system is regarded as a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), then both zero and one are unique by usual definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea. Suppose we define a zero in the complex numbers as an additive identity: a number $z$ such that $z + a = a + z = a$ for all $a$. And suppose there are two of them, $z$ and $z'$. What do you get if you look at $z + z'$?